# Help solving linear programming problem with simplex method

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

> [image]

My friend needs this problem solved, but she doesn't know how. She asked for my help, but the problem is - I don't know either. Could somebody guide me through the process, please?

Comment: It is really nice to see on this site how many friends users have ! Why does not she ask the question by herself ? By the way, welcome to this fantastic site !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the general process in solving these kinds of linear programming questions is as follows:

1. Formulate the problem
2. Augment the problem to get it into a form easy to solve
3. Solve the augmented problem for its basic feasible solution

In this case the problem has already been formulated so you're good there. Now you want to augment the objective function and the constraints so that it is in standard form. Add surplus variables to each constraint to make it into an equality and then to account for the fact that it was already an equality, add artificial variables to turn it into a less then or equal to inequality.For each artificial variable add penalties to your objective function. Then setup the simplex tableau as you usually would and go through the iterations until you have an optimal solution